# How to use sign-in quota (plus.login scope) for Google Plus

Tags: python, google-api

I wrote a scraper to get some of the users' public contents. This scraper fetches the comments, plusoners, resharers, and the user's post. The free quota is 10,000 requests/day if you use API key:

```
   service = apiclient.discovery.build(service_name, service_version,
                                             developerKey=api_key)
```

I'd like to use Sign-in quota to fetch plusoners and resharers (people.list API call). But I couldn't use oauth for this purpose. That is, I don't have any users. I'd like to use the scope (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login) for fetching plusoners and resharers.

In Java, I think the procedure is this: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.Builder.

How can I do it for Python?

Answer (score 0):

There is really lots of documents how to authenticate it with Oauth2.0 but there isn't so much information about how a server side script can authenticate itself without any human presence.

I think I found the most convenient way of doing it with JWT.

```
from apiclient.discovery import build
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client.client import SignedJwtAssertionCredentials

private_key = open("MyProject.p12").read() 
client_email = 'EMAIL'
http_auth = credentials.authorize(Http())
credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(client_email, private_key, 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login')
service.people().list(userId='me', collection='connected').execute()
```

*Note for people who are not careful like me*: Moreover, this authentication method doesn't useful for me because it's for people().list API calls. However, I'd like to use people().listByActivity.